# CSS Flex layout and gap(tailwind example)

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

Let's say, that we have this design:

```
<div className="w-full flex flex-wrap gap-4">
  <div className="w-1/2"></div>
  <div className="w-1/3"></div>
  <div className="w-1/6"></div>
</div>
```

If you don't know tailwind, no problem:

- w-full: width: 100%
- w-1/2 = width: 50%
- w-1/3 = width: 33.33%
- w-1-6 = width: 16.66%
- gap-4 = gap: 16px
- flex = display: flex
- flex-wrap = flex-wrap: wrap;

Now, let's go to the problem. I want these three divs to be in one row( because 50% + 33.33% + 16.66% = 100%) and it's working without a gap, but when I add a gap, it's collapsing due to the gap increasing the space of layout. In the more complex layout, there will be more boxes, with the width being multiple of w-1/6( w-1/3, w-1/2, w-2/3, w-5/6, w-full). How to achieve equal gap without increasing the space, to not wrap, because of gap.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact how the box model works: Gap is added to the width of the box.

You can, however, achieve your desired result by:

- adding padding to each individual element
- removing the padding on the parent container using negative margins

```html
<div class="-mx-2 flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="w-1/2 px-2">A</div>
  <div class="w-1/3 px-2">B</div>
  <div class="w-1/6 px-2">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't seen your answer, but I had also similiar idea for that, but I would need double divs, like in example below: https://play.tailwindcss.com/YzZuEcOaRM

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex` property instead of width

```html
<div class="w-full flex flex-wrap gap-4">
  <div class="flex-[3]"></div>
  <div class="flex-[2]"></div>
  <div class="flex-1"></div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/1vuMBO8Bde)

For demonstration purposes I've created a solution for grid layout - the result will differ slightly because `gap` for grid included within `div` element

Comment: But it doesn't wrap, when I add another divs.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. Maybe use grid then?